# the request url not found in php

Tags: php

my home.php is

```
required("conn.php");
<html>
<body>
<form action="like.php" name="art" method="post">
        <?php 
        //$email=$data['email'];
        ?>
                <table align="center" border="2">
                <tr><th colspan="4"><h2 align="center">Articals</h2></th></tr>
                <tr>    <th>Name</th><th>Artical</th><th>Status</th><th colspan="2">option</th>
                </tr>
        <?php
            $r = mysql_query("select * from ar ");
                while($ro=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
        ?>
        <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $ro["fname"]?></td>
                <td><textarea rows="2" cols="25"><?php echo $ro["post"]?></textarea></td>
                <td><?php echo $ro["status"]?></td>
                <td><a name="like" href="like.php?id=<?php echo $ro['id']?>"> like</a></td>
                <!--<td><a href="delart.php?id=<?php //echo $row["id"]?>" >Delete</a></td>
                <td><a href="edt.php?unm=<?php //echo $row[0]?>">Upadate</a></td>
-->            
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
</form>
</table>
    </body>    
</html>
```

and like.php is

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))    
       {
         header('Location:index.php');  
       }
require("conn.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
mysql_query("insert into `like` ar where id='$id'");


?>
```

when i am click on link like so the error "The requested URL /25-8/like.php was not found on this server." is come pls help i am new to php
i want there to count the no of like and on click on that like button it automatically change to unlike

Comment: Are home.php and like.php in the same directory?

Comment: yes they are in same folder

Comment: Try placing the full path in the href (like "http:  //mysite/like.php"), does it work?

Comment: give me simple code i am new to php... :|

Comment: Try using the full path, for example <a href="http://www.yoursite.com/like.php">Hello</a>
Create a simple test.php page and copy the code replacing www.yoursite.com with your server name. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Paste the following code into a test.php document and tell me if it works, if it does the trick simply copy it instead of your current link <?php $root = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo $root.'/like.php';
?> 

<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$root.'/like.php' ?>">Hello</a>

Answer (score 0):

YOu Must put the home.php and like.php in the same directory?